# Getting Dummies from a dataset using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, machine-learning

I have downloaded the a Heart Disease database. Certain values however, such as `"restecg"` and `"cp"` have more than one possible value. I would like to separate those values into their own columns with values of 0 or 1 and then perform a logistic regression on them. Normally, in python, I would just do this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('bank.csv', header = 0)
data = data.dropna()
dataRefactored = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['...']) #Columns I want to get dummies for
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

If the input was:

```
Slope
  1
  3
  2
  1
```

The output would be:

```
Slope_1 Slope_2 Slope_3
   1      0       0
   0      0       1
   0      1       0
   1      0       0
```

How would I replicate this in JS?

Comment: Idea, please add some sample data and expected output, many javascript people never code in python.

Comment: @jezrael I updated it. Is the question more clear now?

Comment: Yes, now it is perfect :)